# Laravel 5.4 foreach loop does not repeat more than once

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, foreach, laravel-blade

I am building a landing page, I have two foreach loops, the first loop repeats only once even though it should be repeated 6 times, if I remove the second loop it works correctly, the second loop should only be repeated once, and probed with `find(1 );` Without using a second loop, but exactly the same thing happens, any ideas?

My code:

```
@foreach($gaInfo as $gi)
    {{$gi->title}}
<!--Home end-->
<section id="nosotros">
    <div class="padding-one">
        <div class="containr">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 wow fadeInLeft">
                    @if($gi->section == 'abouts' && $gi->lang == $lang)
                    <h2>{{ $gi->title }}</h2>
                    @endif
                    <hr>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-8 wow col-xs-12">
                            <div class="text-center p-margin">
                                @foreach($abouts as $about)
                                    {{$about->description}}
                                @endforeach
                            </div>
                        </div>
@endforeach
```

the $gaInfo contain 6 entries and $abouts contain only one entries, sorry for my bad english.

The controller:

```
$sliders = new slider();
        $abouts = new about();
        $contact = new contact();
        $projects = new project();
        $customers = new customer();
        $services = new service();
        $gacimsInfo = new gacimsInfo();
        $goals = new Goal();
        $views = new View();
        $missions = new Mission();
        $teams = new team();
        $request->lang = 'es';

        $data = [
            'sliders' => $sliders->get(),
            'abouts' => $abouts->get(),
            'contact' => $contact->get(),
            'projects' => $projects->get(),
            'customers' => $customers->get(),
            'services' => $services->get(),
            'gacimsInfo' => $gacimsInfo->get(),
            'lang' => $request->lang,
            'goals' => $goals->get(),
            'views' => $views->get(),
            'missions' => $missions->get(),
            'teams' => $teams->get(),
            ];

        return view('home', $data);
```

Comment: The code seems to be correct. Try to put `{{ dd($gaInfo) }}` and `{{ dd($abouts) }}` after @foreach and check if the variables are correct.

Comment: the variables are correct, I already check it in many ways, and only this way gives me problems and this is the way I need it: /

Comment: Can you show how you manipulate those variables ( $abouts and $gaInfo )

Comment: @RomnickSusa now you can see.

Comment: The code looks correct. We need to debug it little by little. before the `return view('home', $data);` can you `dd($data['abouts']->count())` and let see the result